# How to use sliding menu over tabs in android?

Tags: android, tabs, slidingmenu, slidingdrawer, android-sliding

i used the sliding menu in a project individually and the tabs individually but i failed to combine them in one project .. did any one face this problem ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use tabs in Sliding menu. You should put the layout which have tabs in Sliding menu's second child.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_relative"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_fragment_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:showDividers="none" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Comment: you mean as a fragmentActivity ?

Comment: A fragment activity which has a Sliding menu, can have a fragment which has tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this amazing class :) http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html